# How do I texture paint?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting

I'm totally new to the whole texture painting process and I can't get the paint thing to work. Can someone explain the basic way to paint on a simple object to me?

Comment: you should follow some tutorials on youtube, it's a little bit tedious to explain with a post, or please explain where you're stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.First you make a new image in the UV/Image Editor that is blank with your favorite resolution

2.You make a material and in the node editor of that material you add a new image node and select the image you made in the UV/Image editor

3.With your object selected you go into texture paint and paint what you want.

4.Dont forget to save the image you painted on because it will not be saved when you save the blend file

I recommend to watch a tutorial on youtube for that

Comment: tried that, doesn't seem to work. Here is my blend file: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pfj41o312dbvus/first_texture_paint.blend.zip?dl=0] please tell me what I am missing.

Comment: also, unwrap your object, otherwise you wont be able to paint on it... btw, impossible to download your file, please use another website, like wetransfer

Comment: @moonboots please don't recommend wetransfer for uploading files. Once the link expires then nobody can download anything any more. To upload files use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/